# Where can the z3 axiom profiler be found?

Tags: z3

There are [many references](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Z3%20Axiom%20Profiler) made to a tool for debugging Z3 traces called the "Z3 Axiom Profiler". I have found [code which is part of the VCC project](http://vcc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#vcc/Tools/Z3Visualizer/Z3Visualizer/Z3AxiomProfiler.cs), that appears to be the axiom profiler and is three years old. Is building from these VCC sources the correct way to obtain the profiler, or is there a more recent version somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the latest version. You can find an executable in the binary VCC distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I supervised a student (Frederik Rothenberger) who worked on various improvements to the previous axiom profiler. You might like to try the newer version out, which includes many bug-fixes and new visualisations for instantiation graphs.

The newer version is available here:

https://bitbucket.org/viperproject/axiom-profiler

and Frederik's project report is here, in case useful:

http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:48774/eth-48774-01.pdf

Please let me know how you get on, if you do try it.

Alex Summers ( alexander.summers@inf.ethz.ch )